# PHP Imagick - setTextEncoding() function doesn't work

Tags: php, encoding, imagemagick, imagick

I'm trying to add some text on a Imagick object.

However I use setTextEncoding() function, it still doesn't work.

```
.......

$draw = new ImagickDraw();
$draw->setTextEncoding('utf-8');
$draw->setFont($fpath.'/process/ARIAL.TTF'); 
$draw->setFontSize(80);
$draw->setFillColor("#ffffff");

/*** annotate the text on the image ***/
$imageOrg->annotateImage($draw, 60, 100, 0, "onur küçükkeçe");

........
```

and as a result I get,

```
onur kÃ¼Ã§Ã¼kkeÃ§e
```

Any idea why it's not working?

Thanks in advance.

**UPDATE**

if I set a $text variable to something like chr(252) then I get a proper result

```
$text=chr(252);
$imageOrg->annotateImage($draw, 60, 100, 0, $text);
```

as a result I get

```
ü
```

**UPDATE II**

Finally I found what causing this.

The problem occurs because the charset of the document is not defined but if set a charset for the script then imagick doesn't work because the type of the document needs to be set to image/png.

But I don't know how can I fix it.

Comment: If you solve the problem yourself, it's probably best to post the fix as an answer instead of as an update to the question. That way you can accept it, others can upvote it, and your question gets removed from the Unanswered Questions list.

Comment: @JeffreyBlake I couldn't solve the problem yet. It occurs because the encoding of the document is not defined.

Comment: My mistake. When I saw your update, I thought you were stating that you had solved it.

Comment: Is your actual PHP script (the code itself) encoded in UTF-8?

Comment: @JohnFlatness I opened the document in notepad and saved it in UTF-8 but then imagick cannot output the image, only some many characters

Comment: You do not say if you are saving the image or just displaying it. What happens if you have a page with the Imagick code and the headers set to image/png and you then use that on your main page with <img src="path_to_page_with_imagick_code.php">

Comment: @Bonzo Problem occurred in both way, and in both way characters seemed broken in the image, but I found the solution, utf8_decode() function fixes it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok. I found the solution.

php **utf8_decode()** function solves the problem

```
.......

$draw = new ImagickDraw();
$draw->setTextEncoding('utf-8');
$draw->setFont($fpath.'/process/ARIAL.TTF'); 
$draw->setFontSize(80);
$draw->setFillColor("#ffffff");

/*** annotate the text on the image ***/
$imageOrg->annotateImage($draw, 60, 100, 0, utf8_decode("onur küçükkeçe"));

........
```

Comment: Hi I tried your solution to my problem. But it still does not work. Maybe I did not set the utf-8 format correctly. How do I ensure that?

My problem is stated here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11101544/how-to-use-imagick-annotateimage-for-chinese-text